# Avro: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Expected long. Got START_OBJECT

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

I am working on an Avro schema and trying to create a testing data to test it with Kafa, but when I produce the message got this error: "Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Expected long. Got START_OBJECT"
The Schema I created is like this:

```
{
    "name": "MyClass",
    "type": "record",
    "namespace": "com.acme.avro",
    "doc":"This schema is for streaming information",
    "fields":[
        {"name":"batchId", "type": "long"},
        {"name":"status", "type": {"type": "enum", "name": "PlannedTripRequestedStatus", "namespace":"com.acme.avro.Dtos", "symbols":["COMPLETED", "FAILED"]}},
        {"name":"runRefId", "type": "int"},
        {"name":"tripId", "type": ["null", "int"]},
        {"name": "referenceNumber", "type": ["null", "string"]},
        {"name":"errorMessage", "type": ["null", "string"]}
    ]
}
```

The testing data is like this:

```
{
    "batchId": {
        "long": 3
    },
    "status": "COMPLETED",
    "runRefId": {
        "int": 1000
    },
    "tripId": {
        "int": 200
    },
    "referenceNumber": {
        "string": "ReferenceNumber1111"
    },
    "errorMessage": {
        "string": "Hello World"
    }
}
```

However, when I registered this schema and try to produce a message with Confluent console tool, I got the error: **org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Expected long. Got START_OBJECT** The whole error message is like this:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing {"batchId": ...} to Avro of schema {"type":...}" at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.AvroMessageReader.readFrom(AvroMessageReader.java:134)
    at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.SchemaMessageReader.readMessage(SchemaMessageReader.java:325)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer$.main(ConsoleProducer.scala:51)
    at kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer.main(ConsoleProducer.scala)
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Expected long. Got START_OBJECT
    at org.apache.avro.io.JsonDecoder.error(JsonDecoder.java:511)
    at org.apache.avro.io.JsonDecoder.readLong(JsonDecoder.java:177)
    at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readLong(ResolvingDecoder.java:169)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:197)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:160)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:259)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:247)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:179)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:160)
    at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:153)
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.avro.AvroSchemaUtils.toObject(AvroSchemaUtils.java:213)
    at io.confluent.kafka.formatter.AvroMessageReader.readFrom(AvroMessageReader.java:124)
```

Does any know what I did wrong with my schema or test data? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You only need the type object if the type is unclear (union of string or number, for example), or its nullable.

For batchId and runRefId, just use simple values

Comment: Thank you so much! It works when I change the batchId and runRefId to number like this: {"batchId": 3,"status":"COMPLETED","runRefId":1000,"tripId":{"int":200},"referenceNumber":{"string":"referenceNumber1111"},"errorMessage":{"string":"Hello World"}}. However, if I change the tripId to number, it's broken again. Can I ask why I cannot use simple value for tripId here? or any avro schema json validation documents I can refer to? Thank you again

Comment: @ZichenMa As answered, nullable fields need the type information

Comment: The reason you can't use a simple value for tripId is because it is a union and the specification states that unions need the type information (unless the value is null). You can read that part of the specification here: https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#json_encoding